# When I run the node.js server, nothing happens

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there anyone who's familiar with Node.js and mongoDB?
Whenever I run the server, nothing happens. I'm supposed to see that console.log("WE JUST SAVED A CAT TO THE DB")

Here's the code of my app.js:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/cat_app", {
  useMongoClient: true
});
var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  temperament: String
});
var Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);
// Add a new cat to the DB
var george = new Cat({
  name: "George",
  age: 11,
  temperament: "Grouchy"
});
george.save(function(err, cat) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG!")
  } else {
    console.log("WE JUST SAVED A CAT TO THE DB!")
    console.log(cat);
  }
});
// Retrieve all cats from the DB and console.log each one
```

So is there any mistake up there?

Comment: There needs to be a app.listen call in app.js

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: That code looks more like a client than a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

you start mongod //mongo server either though bash or file.

then start mongo // connect to your server

then node cats.js // in my case it's southpark.js

with code inside like this// and that should work.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/SP_app');


var spSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    temperament:String 
}); 


var SP = mongoose.model('SP', spSchema);

var eric = new SP({ 
    name:'Butters',
    age:10,
    temperament:'confused' 
});

eric.save(function(err, sp){ 
    if(err){  
        console.log("404 Something's Wrong") 
    }   else{ 
        console.log('WE JUST SAVED A CHARACTER TO THE DB:') 
        console.log(sp);  
    }
});
```

Comment: if you run node app.js nothing happens, u need to set up Windows Environment. or just use cmd/bash cd c:\myNodeApp\   or in bash mode cd /c/myNodeApp  to the app location file then type node app in cmd/bash